# DynamoDB consistent read results in schema error

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto, distributed

I am trying to interact with a DynamoDB table from python using boto. I want all reads/writes to be quorum consistency to ensure that reads sent out immediately after writes always reflect the correct data.

NOTE: my table is set up with "phone_number" as the hash key and first_name+last_name as a secondary index. And for the purposes of this question one (and only one) item exists in the db (first_name="Paranoid", last_name="Android", phone_number="42")

The following code works as expected:

```
customer = customers.get_item(phone_number="42")
```

While this statement:

```
customer = customers.get_item(phone_number="42", consistent_read=True)
```

fails with the following error:

```
boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The provided key element does not match the schema', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}
```

Could this be the result of some hidden data corruption due to failed requests in the past? (for example two concurrent and different writes executed at eventual consistency)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are calling the [get_item](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb.html#boto.dynamodb.table.Table.get_item) method so the issue is with how you are passing parameters.

```
get_item(hash_key, range_key=None, attributes_to_get=None, consistent_read=False, item_class=<class 'boto.dynamodb.item.Item'>)
```

Which would mean you should be calling the API like:

```
customer = customers.get_item(hash_key="42", consistent_read=True)
```

I'm not sure why the original call you were making was working.

---

To address your concerns about data corruption and eventual consistency, it is highly unlike that any API call you could make to DynamoDB could result in it getting into a bad state outside of you sending it bad data for an item.  DynamoDB is a highly tested solution that provides exceptional availability and goes to extraordinary lengths to take care of the data you send it.

Eventual consistency is something to be aware of with DynamoDB, but generally speaking it is not something that causes many issues depending on the specifics of the use case.  While AWS does not provide specific metrics on what "eventually consistent" look like, in day-to-day use it is normal to be able to read out records that were just written/modified under a second even when eventually consistent reads.

As for performing multiple writes simultaneously on the same object, DynamoDB writes are always strongly consistent.  You can utilize [conditional writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) with DynamoDB if you are worried about an individual item being modified at the same time resulting in unexpected behavior which will allow writes to fail and your application logic to deal with any issues that arise.