# DynamoDB update after updated it's again going back old value

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update number of items in dynamoDb, I have written below function

```
def put_count_in_table(pk, sk, max_price, min_price, mean_price, total_count):

    dynamodb = getDynamoDb()

    table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_ITEM_CATEGORIES)

    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'pk': pk,
            'sk': sk,
        },
        UpdateExpression="set max_price=:m, min_price=:n, mid_price=:p, total_count=:q",

        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':m': max_price,
            ':n': min_price,
            ':p': mean_price,
            ':q': total_count
        }
    )
    return response
```

For items update I have call the function by loop through like below

```
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    shopItem = getShopItem(item)
    res = put_count_in_table(shopItem['pk'], shopItem['sk'], shopItem['max_price'],
                                    shopItem['min_price'], shopItem['mid_price'], shopItem['total_count'])
```

Problem is some product is updating fine, but for some case some products are updating but after 2-3 sec  it's going back again in old value. I have given sleep(3) before update but the result is same. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using consistent read?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html
See more data in similar thread [DynamoDB consistent read results in schema error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775295/dynamodb-consistent-read-results-in-schema-error)

```
data = table.get_item(phone_number="42", consistent_read=True)
```